# how to distinct the spark rdd by the key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, transformation, rdd

now, I have a RDD, which the records in the RDD are as follows:

```
key1  value1
key1  value2
key2  value3
key3  value4
key3  value5
```

I want to  get the RDD records which have different keys ,as follows:

```
key1  value1
key2  value3
key3  value4
```

I can just use the spark-core APIs and don't aggregate  values of the same key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with [`PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions). Assuming you have an `RDD[(K, V)]`:

```
rdd.reduceByKey((a, b) => if (someCondition) a else b)
```

Answer (score 1):

With data frames and `collect_set`:

```
sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("k", "v")
  .groupBy("k")
  .agg(collect_set(col("v")))
```

Comment: thanks but here I can not use the sqlContext. I can just use the APIs in the spark-core.

Comment: @CaizhengLiu in this case then I would recommend you to edit your question and add any restriction and details would help answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option. It's in `PySpark`, but I'm almost sure that there should be a similar way in Scala.

Assuming again that you have a RDD with (key, value) elements, then

**The short answer is,**

```
    rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(list).map(lambda t: (t[0],t[1][0]))
```

**The full working code sample is,**

```
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    SparkContext._active_spark_context.stop()
    spConf = SparkConf()
    spConf.setAppName('unique_keys')
    sc = SparkContext(conf=spConf)

    sample_data = sc.parallelize([('k1','v1'),('k1','v2'),('k2','v3'),('k3','v4'),('k3','v5')],3)
    print('original rdd {}'.format(sorted(sample_data.collect(),key = lambda t: t[0])))
    print('original rdd has {} unique elements'.format(sample_data.distinct().count()))
    print('original rdd has {} unique keys'.format(sample_data.map(lambda t: t[0]).distinct().count()))

    sample_data = sample_data.groupByKey().mapValues(list).map(lambda t: (t[0],t[1][0]))
    print('rdd with unique keys {}'.format(sorted(sample_data.collect()),key = lambda t: t[0]))
```

**Output,**

```
original rdd [('k1', 'v1'), ('k1', 'v2'), ('k2', 'v3'), ('k3', 'v4'), ('k3', 'v5')]
original rdd has 5 unique elements
original rdd has 3 unique keys
rdd with unique keys [('k1', 'v2'), ('k2', 'v3'), ('k3', 'v4')]
```